# How can I retrieve message content in a custom Discord client using Ruby?

Tags: json, ruby, websocket, discord, client

I am having an issue with a custom Discord client I created using Ruby that is only meant for reading messages. When attempting to retrieve message content, I am receiving nothing and a strange error, I cannot figure out why. Below is the code I am using:

```
require 'websocket-client-simple'
require 'json'

token = 'My discord account token (Not a bot token!)'
url = 'wss://gateway.discord.gg'
version = '9'
encoding = 'json'

client = WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect("#{url}/?v=#{version}&encoding=#{encoding}")

client.on(:open) do
  client.send({ op: 2, d: { token: token, intents: 513, properties: { '$os': 'linux', '$browser': 'chrome', '$device': '' } } }.to_json)
end

client.on(:message) do |msg|
  data = JSON.parse(msg.data)
  if data['op'] == 0 && !data['d']['webhooks']
    channel_id = data['d']['channel_id'] || ''
    username = data['d']['author']['username'] || ''
    content = data['d']['content'] || ''
    puts "[#{channel_id}] <#{username}> #{content}"
  end
end

client.on(:error) do |e|
  puts "Error: #{e.message}"
end

client.on(:close) do |e|
  puts "Closed: #{e}"
end

at_exit do
  client&.close
end

loop do
  # do something else while listening
end
```

After running the program and sending several messages in Discord, I received the following output:

```
alex@Alexs-PC:/media/alex/2-TB/STORAGE/Absolute-Solver/ASLDC/ASLDC-4.0$ ruby main.rb
Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
[1116271442372333572] <sobinec> 
[1116271442372333572] <sobinec> 
[1116271442372333572] <sobinec> 
[1116271442372333572] <sobinec> 
[1116271442372333572] <sobinec> 
Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
[1116271442372333572] <sobinec> 
[1116271442372333572] <sobinec> 
[1116271442372333572] <sobinec> 
[1116271442372333572] <sobinec> 
Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
[1116271442372333572] <sobinec> 
[1116271442372333572] <sobinec> 
Error: 809: unexpected token at ''
```

As you can see from the output, I am unable to retrieve message content and am receiving a strange error. I am not able to use a bot token or certain bot libraries like discordrb since they do not work properly with a Discord account token. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Issue: Not receiving expected response and error-free messages from ChatGPT

Expected outcome: Receiving sent messages and error-free responses

Steps taken:

1. Tried asking ChatGPT for assistance
2. Did not receive helpful responses

Expected sent messages, no errors. Asked ChatGPT but unhelpful.

Comment: If you don't know if a certain path in the structure exists, use [`dig`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/hash#method-i-dig) to safely navigate, as in `data.dig('d','webhooks')`

Comment: I'd also recommend judicious use of `pp` here to dump out what you're getting so you can verify any assumptions made.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message `Error: 809: unexpected token at ''` incoming message is not a valid JSON document. So trying to parse this message as a JSON raises that error.

To make your code safe change it like that:

```rb
client.on(:message) do |msg|
  data = JSON.parse(msg.data)
  if data['op'] == 0 && !data['d']['webhooks']
    channel_id = data['d']['channel_id'] || ''
    username = data['d']['author']['username'] || ''
    content = data['d']['content'] || ''
    puts "[#{channel_id}] <#{username}> #{content}"
  end
rescue => e
  puts "Error occurred: #{e} on #{msg}"
end
```

**UPD**: And that helps to identify the problem: there is no "author" key in received message. Key "user" should be used instead:

```rb
    username = data['d']['user']['username'] || ''
```

Comment: It appears that the JSON file in question is valid; however, due to its size, I cannot confirm its validity with certainty. I kindly request that you test the file on your machine using your Discord account token. Your expertise would be of great help in resolving this matter. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Have you tried a patch above?

Comment: Certainly worth scoping the `rescue` down from *everything* to expected JSON decoding errors.

Comment: Now, it's not even show the usernames, and also I got an error:

[] <Lisa&Sophie4EVER> 
Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Error: 809: unexpected token at ''